# Why the button is located on the left and not under the picture?

Tags: html, css

Why the button is located on the left and not under the picture?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/My.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="~/Images/FirstImage.jpg" class="img" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Buy</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because it's inline block and image inline

Comment: add display:block to your button in css

Comment: Note: the `<meta>`, `<link>` and `<img>` tags do not use or need a closing slash and never have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image is an inline element such as `span`,  not block element such as `div`, so next element is following the image on the same line.

To make it block element you can put the image inside the div:

```
<div><img ...></div>
```

or use style to make it block element

```
<img style="display: block;" >
```

or using the css annotation:

```
.img { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because neither image or button are block elements. This doesn't have anything to do with bootstrap.

```css
img {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/My.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="https://placebear.com/100/100" class="img" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Buy</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this `CSS` rule:

```
.panel-body { display: grid; }
```

Or this one:

```
.img { display: block; }
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rqbs4ur6/)  is the jsfiddle